# how do I express that women who visit somewhere have no distinct age specific

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

I want to put more in to this sentence to say about that young women, old women all visit help desk. In other words, there is no varying age change in visiting help desk services.

**Women seem to use help desk services more often than men according to that fact that approximately only two men out of 15 to 20 clients were spotted across three help desk sessions. Women of all ages seem to visit the help desk services**

Comment: This seems too broad a question, but I might just say the following if I were being simplistic about it: *Women, **regardless of age**, seem to use . . .* But there are many ways of expressing this—in one or two sentences, or even more. It would depend on how detailed you want to get, how much clarification from supporting data you want to provide, and so on.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: Reminds me of the Ringling Bros. address..."..and children of all ages". Now _that_ is boad.